# Filter same category images and json files into another folder in google drive using google colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I want only filter wildfire related json files inside the `label` folder  to another folder and wildfire label `targets` folder images to another drive folder. How to do it?
Here is my dataset link:

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1lGD1LSnPnyoCOLfPXiZ_Y4zWgyh93ltn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this code:

```
    from google.colab import drive
    drive.mount('/content/drive')

    import os 
    import json 
    import shutil

    main_folder_path = "/content/drive/MyDrive/FYP_dataset/dataset_extract/train"
    images_folder_path = main_folder_path+"/targets"
    labels_folder_path = main_folder_path+"/labels"
    categorized_folder_path = "/content/drive/My Drive/categorized"

    os.chdir(main_folder_path)
    for json_filename in os.listdir(labels_folder_path):
      json_path = os.path.join(main_folder_path, "labels", json_filename)
      f = open(json_path, 'r')
      data = json.load(f)
      disaster_type = data["metadata"]["disaster_type"]
      img_name = data["metadata"]["img_name"]
      new_image = img_name.split(".")[0]+"_target.png"
      print("disaster:", disaster_type, "image:", img_name)
      f.close()
      img_filepath = os.path.join(main_folder_path, "targets", new_image)
      category_folderpath_for_labels = os.path.join(categorized_folder_path, "labels", "fire")
      category_folderpath_for_images = os.path.join(categorized_folder_path, "targets", "fire")
      if os.path.exists(img_filepath):
        if not os.path.exists(category_folderpath_for_labels):
          os.mkdir(category_folderpath_for_labels)
        if not os.path.exists(category_folderpath_for_images):
          os.mkdir(category_folderpath_for_images)
      if disaster_type == "fire":
       shutil.copy(json_path, category_folderpath_for_labels)
       shutil.copy(img_filepath, category_folderpath_for_images)
```

If file paths not found error occurs, please create those target folders in the drive and try again.